# In Vim, can I run an autocommand on entering Command-line mode?

Tags: vim

The autocommand I would like to run is

```
au CmdlineModeEnter * wall
```

except that CmdlineModeEnter does not exist. I used to have a mapping defined like

```
nnoremap : :wall<CR>:
```

which worked fine except that the ":wall" flashing up was visible and distracting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function! CmdlineEnter()
    silent! wall
    call feedkeys(":", 'n')
endfun

noremap <silent> : :call CmdlineEnter()<CR>
```

Comment: @Owen strictly speaking, [*Ex mode* is what you enter with `Q`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Ex-mode), not `:`: [`:` enters *Command-line mode* (as do `/` and `?`).](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:)

Comment: Owen added `silent!` to suppress warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
nnoremap <silent> : :wall<CR>:
```

See

```
:help :map-<silent>
```

Comment: Yes, it does make the ":wall" go away... unfortunately it also hides the leading : until I type the next char ;). Oh well I think I'm just too picky.